# Loaded die problem - how to calculate the probability that both 1 and 2 occur

Tags: probability, statistics

A die is loaded to give the probabilities:

$$P(1)=0.3$$
$$P(2)=0.1$$
$$P(3)=0.15$$
$$P(4)=0.15$$
$$P(5)=0.15$$
$$P(6)=0.15$$

and thrown 8 times. Find the probability that both 1 and 2 occur.

This problem seems funnily easy but I can't see how to solve it without brute-forcing all the combinations...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:  You can use inclusion/exclusion.  Calculate the chance that 1 doesn't occur, which is $0.7^8$ and the chance that 2 doesn't occur.  Add them together, but you have double counted the cases where neither occurs, so deduct the chance which neither occurs.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to find the probability that $1$ or $2$ or both **fail** to occur.

Comment: Ah, misread "both fail."